# struct representation in memory on 64 bit machine

Tags: c

For my curiosity I have written a program which was to show each byte of my struct. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MAX_INT 2147483647
#define MAX_LONG 9223372036854775807

typedef struct _serialize_test{
   char a;
   unsigned int b;
   char ab;
   unsigned long long int c;
}serialize_test_t;


int main(int argc, char**argv){
   serialize_test_t *t;
   t = malloc(sizeof(serialize_test_t));
   t->a = 'A';
   t->ab = 'N';
   t->b = MAX_INT;
   t->c = MAX_LONG;

   printf("%x %x %x %x %d %d\n", t->a, t->b, t->ab, t->c, sizeof(serialize_test_t), sizeof(unsigned long long int));

   char *ptr = (char *)t;

   int i;
   for (i=0; i < sizeof(serialize_test_t) - 1; i++){
      printf("%x = %x\n", ptr + i, *(ptr + i));
   }

   return 0;
}
```

and here is the output:

```
41 7fffffff 4e ffffffff 24 8
26b2010 = 41
26b2011 = 0
26b2012 = 0
26b2013 = 0
26b2014 = ffffffff
26b2015 = ffffffff
26b2016 = ffffffff
26b2017 = 7f
26b2018 = 4e
26b2019 = 0
26b201a = 0
26b201b = 0
26b201c = 0
26b201d = 0
26b201e = 0
26b201f = 0
26b2020 = ffffffff
26b2021 = ffffffff
26b2022 = ffffffff
26b2023 = ffffffff
26b2024 = ffffffff
26b2025 = ffffffff
26b2026 = ffffffff
```

And here is the question:
if `sizeof(long long int) is 8`, then why `sizeof(serialize_test_t) is 24` instead of 32 - I always thought that size of struct is rounded to largest type and multiplied by number of fields like here for example: 8(bytes)*4(fields) = 32(bytes) — by default, with no pragma pack directives?

Also when I cast that struct to `char *` I can see from the output that the offset between values in memory is not 8 bytes. Can you give me a clue? Or maybe this is just some compiler optimizations?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong.  The standard doesn't say anything about packing or padding other than that it might be there.

Comment: the padding requirements aren't C or even arch dependent, but ABI dependent, your will likely be getting answers specific to the x86_64 ABI's, the two main ones, win64 and System V (everything else) will be pretty similar.

Comment: The standard says one thing about padding in structs: there won't be any before the first element of the struct.  Whether there is any padding and where it occurs other than before the first element is up to the compiler.  But for any struct type `struct X x;`, the address of `x` is also the address of the first element of `x` (albeit the address types are different).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On modern 32-bit machines like the SPARC or the Intel [34]86, or any Motorola chip from the 68020 up, each data iten must usually be ``self-aligned'', beginning on an address that is a multiple of its type size. Thus, 32-bit types must begin on a 32-bit boundary, 16-bit types on a 16-bit boundary, 8-bit types may begin anywhere, struct/array/union types have the alignment of their most restrictive member.

The total size of the structure will depend on the packing.In your case it's going as 8 byte so final structure will look like

```
typedef struct _serialize_test{

   char a;//size 1 byte

   padding for 3 Byte;

   unsigned int b;//size 4 Byte

   char ab;//size 1 Byte again

   padding of 7 byte;

   unsigned long long int c;//size 8 byte

}serialize_test_t;
```

in this manner first two and last two are aligned properly and total size reaches upto 24.

Comment: Are you sure that the M68000, M68008, M68010 were any different from the M68020?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler ->68020 improvement over 68010,having 32-bit arithmetic logic unit (ALU), The previous 68000 and 68010 processors could only access word (16 bit) and longword (32 bit) data if it were word-aligned.The 68020 had no alignment restrictions on data access.

Comment: But for this specific case, wouldn't a 68000 compiler still align the struct members in the same manner as in the OP's post? Because there are no 16 bit accesses in this specific example.

Comment: So you're saying that M68020 doesn't require data to be 'self-aligned' after all?  That isn't the impression I got from your main answer, but your comment suggests otherwise.  Bus errors or equivalent from misaligned accesses (or double fetches, or whatever) are somewhat tangential to the memory layout.  There was no change that I'm aware of between the M68000 and M68020 in the way that compilers would lay out the structures, which was the main point I was making.

Comment: @Lundin ya you are right, but due to lack on knowledge on 16 bit,i started my answer specific to 32 bit only. from next time i will take care of this too.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the alignment chosen by your compiler.  However, you can reasonably expect the following defaults:

```
typedef struct _serialize_test{
   char a;                       // Requires 1-byte alignment
   unsigned int b;               // Requires 4-byte alignment
   char ab;                      // Requires 1-byte alignment
   unsigned long long int c;     // Requires 4- or 8-byte alignment, depending on native register size
}serialize_test_t;
```

Given the above requirements, the first field will be at offset zero.

Field `b` will start at offset 4 (after 3 bytes padding).

The next field starts at offset 8 (no padding required).

The next field starts at offset 12 (32-bit) or 16 (64-bit) (after another 3 or 7 bytes padding).

This gives you a total size of 20 or 24, depending on the alignment requirements for `long long` on your platform.

GCC has an [`offsetof`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Offsetof.html) function that you can use to identify the offset of any particular member, or you can define one yourself:

```
// modulo errors in parentheses...
#define offsetof(TYPE,MEMBER) (int)((char *)&((TYPE *)0)->MEMBER - (char *)((TYPE *)0))
```

Which basically calculates the offset using the difference in address using an imaginary base address for the aggregate type.

Answer (score 0):

The padding is generally added so that the struct is a multiple of the word size (in this case 8)

So the first 2 fields are in one 8 byte chunk. The third field is in another 8 byte chunk and the last is in one 8 byte chunk. For a total of 24 bytes.

```
char 
padding
padding
padding
unsigned int
unsigned int
unsigned int
unsigned int
char                            // Word Boundary
padding
padding
padding
padding
padding
padding
padding
unsigned long long int           // Word Boundary
unsigned long long int
unsigned long long int
unsigned long long int
unsigned long long int
unsigned long long int
unsigned long long int
unsigned long long int
```

Answer (score 0):

Has to do with alignment.

The size of the struct is not rounded to the largest type and multiplied by the fields.  The bytes are aligned each by their respective types: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Architectures

Alignment works in that the type must appear in a memory address that is a multiple of its size, so:

Char is 1 byte aligned, so it can appear anywhere in memory that is a multiple of 1 (anywhere).

The unsigned int is needs to start at an address that is a multiple of 4.

The char can be anywhere.

and then the long long needs to be in a multiple of 8.

If you take a look at the addresses, this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is only concerned about the individual alignment of the struct members, one by one. It does not think about the struct as whole. Because on the binary level a struct does not exist, just a chunk of individual variables allocated at a certain address offset. There's no such thing as "struct round-up", the compiler couldn't care less about how large struct is, as long as all struct members are properly aligned.

The C standard says nothing about the manner of padding, apart from that a compiler is not allowed to add padding bytes at the very beginning of the struct. Apart from that, the compiler is free to add any number of padding bytes anywhere in the struct. It could 999 padding bytes and it would still conform to the standard.

So the compiler goes through the struct and sees: here's a char, it needs alignment. In this case, the CPU can probably handle 32 bit accesses, i.e. 4 byte alignment. Because it only adds 3 padding bytes.

Next it spots a 32 bit int, no alignment required, it is left as it is. Then another char, 3 padding bytes, then a 64 bit int, no alignment required.

Comment: There's one place that compiler considers the 'struct as a whole', which is ensuring that the structure will be correctly aligned when an array of them is allocated.  Suppose there was another single `char d;` field after the `unsigned long long`; the structure would be a multiple of 8 bytes long (assuming `unsigned long long` needs to be 8-byte aligned), so there'd be 7 padding bytes after the hypothetical `d`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That is true, but that case is more related to the nature of an array than of a struct. An array of characters could also in theory get the same padding between members, for alignment reasons. I can't remember if something in the C standard wouldn't allow such padding inside an array.